# What is the difference between "a query" and " a request"?

Tags: meaning, differences

We often see both terms, *query* and *request* in multiple notions in computer science.
While the meaning of *request* is simple to a non-english native speaker, I don't seem to be able to find an analogy to *query* in Russian language (my native one), to deeply feel the difference between the meanings of two words.

Comment: A query is a request that returns an answer (or value). A request can result in anything (or nothing).

Comment: A *query" is a question; e.g., "Do you have this book in stock?" A request asks for something; e.g., "I would like you to send the book by Express Mail if you can."

Comment: In programming "a query" is a result of a Select request. So request is требование (запрос, заявка) and query is запрос (просьба). I'm also russian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A QUERY is an inquiry.

They are both requests but the difference is that the QUERY is a precise request. In informatics, if you need information about something you need to send a specific request with precise information.

"I queried information about user account Maxim Pavlov" = "I need to know about this website users. In particular, I need to know if there is any Maxim Pavlov registered on this site"